# How does UIKit actually render elements onto the screen?

Tags: uikit, rendering, core-graphics

This is a more general question on screen rendering, but will be using UIKit as an example. When we write `UIView...` this is an abstraction of an element in UIKit which uses CoreGraphics which uses x which uses y. At the end of the day to render a view or a label there has to be a common ancestor. I have look into this and can only come to one conclusion and curious to see if that is correct. At the base level is a rendering software like OpenGL in this case Metal used to handle the rendering of UIKit elements? All I’m trying to uncover each layer of abstraction for drawing a UILabel/UIView onto the screen.